# Android material design compatibility - duplicate layouts?

Tags: android, material-design

Everything I'm reading so far about backwards compatibility with material design indicates that I have to maintain two separate sets of layout files if I want to use any material design features and maintain backward compatibility,  one for 21+, and one for pre-21.  Needless to say, this really sucks.  Every time I want to change something in the UI, I have to change it twice.  Am I correct in this, or is there a cool workaround I have not found?

It seems that an alternative is to set all the material design attributes in Java instead of XML, wrapped in a check against the current SDK version.  I would consider this pretty ugly, but it might be better than duplicating layouts.  Maybe a clever way to hide it away would make it more tolerable.

I can't think of anything other than these two bad solutions - has anyone found something better?

Comment: What exactly are you needing to duplicate? Can you show an example layout?

Comment: Any layout, it doesn't matter.  If I want to set a view's elevation on a layout XML file and still maintain backward compatibility, now I need two files, because I can't set elevation for pre-21 SDKs.  So I have to make a copy of the layout file for `layout-21` and another copy for `layout`.

Comment: Except that unknown tags are ignored on older versions - they just won't do anything (which is what lint warns you about). Please be specific in what issues you are running into. Is it specifically around elevation or also something else?

Answer (score 0):

ianhanniballake is right, you can just leave the new tags in the file.  I was basing my ire on this from the documentation:

> If the layouts that you design according to the material design
>   guidelines do not use any of the new XML attributes introduced in
>   Android 5.0 (API level 21), they will work on previous versions of
>   Android. Otherwise, you can provide alternative layouts. You can also
>   provide alternative layouts to customize how your app looks on earlier
>   versions of Android.
>
> Create your layout files for Android 5.0 (API level 21) inside
>   res/layout-v21/ and your alternative layout files for earlier versions
>   of Android inside res/layout/. For example, res/layout/my_activity.xml
>   is an alternative layout for res/layout-v21/my_activity.xml.

Which I think clearly says to use new attributes you have to duplicate your files.  It seems that is not the case after all.  Thanks.